# Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, pdo

I want to make a function to check if a user already exist in a db. The function is stored in a php file called `checks.php` and must return a value.

```
require 'database.php';
function exist_user( $username){
 $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :$username');       
 $sth->bindParam(':email', $username);
 $sth->execute();
 return ($sth->rowCount() == 0) ?  true :  false;
}
```

My database.php file:

```
$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'auth';
try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;", $username, 
  $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  die( "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

I call to `exist_user()` in another php file called `register.php`:

```
require 'database.php';
require 'checks.php';

if (!exist_user($username)) {
  //insert in the db
else{
  //echo some message error 
}
```

The error poops up on this sentence: **$sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :$username');**

I have tried in the `checks.php` file:

1. Move the code from `database.php to checks.php`
2. Set `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` after php tag
3. I saw different answers on this type of error but none helped me to solve this.

Comment: `$conn` doesn't exist within the [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of the `exist_user` function

Comment: Tried `$sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email');` instead ?

Comment: @BlitZ it should even be `email = :email` since he tries to bind `$username` to `:email` on the next line.

Comment: @Twinfriends yeah, I'm noticed just before you posted. Thanks.

Comment: `rowCount` is not the best function for PDO and selects, `If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php Use `select count(*) ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few errors.

*Firstly:* `$conn` doesn't exist within the [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of the `user_exist` function; you'll need to either pass it in as a parameter or access it with the `global` keyword.

```
function exist_user($conn, $username){
    $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :$username');       
    ...
}
```

... or ...

```
function exist_user($username){
    global $conn;
    $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :$username');       
    ...
}
```

---

*Secondly:* your parameter binding is somewhat broken:

```
$sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :$username');       
$sth->bindParam(':email', $username);
```

That would be attempting to literally bind a parameter called `$username` - you probably just want `:username`.

And the parameter you're binding then isn't `:email` but `:username` - i.e.

```
$sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :username');       
$sth->bindParam(':username', $username);
```

---

*Finally:* - you *might* get away with using `return ($sth->rowCount() == 0) ?  true :  false;` to return a success state but technically `rowCount()` returns the number of *affected* rows, not retrieved:

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.
>
> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.

**However** if you just need to determine whether a user exists you can use something like:

```
function exist_user($conn, $username) {
    $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT 1 AS user_exists FROM users WHERE email = :username');        
    $sth->bindParam(':username', $username);
    
    if($sth->execute()) {
        $result = $stc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return !empty($result['user_exists']);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So the parameter **$username** than i'm passing to the function should not be written like ":$username" but insted ":username" in the SELECT?

Comment: In the SQL statement, yes, you're effectively just creating a placeholder label - when you use `bindParam` you assign the value to that placeholder e.g. `$sth->bindParam(':username', $username);` assigns the value `$username` to the placeholder `:username` in the SQL @Mi7ai

Comment: I will make changes to the code about rowCount() and other stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Made a slight tweak to the return since, technically, `$sth->execute()` would return true as long as the SQL is OK rather than it being OK **and** finding an existing user ;) @Mi7ai

Answer (score 0):

The `$conn` object is a global object which does not exist in the function scope, a global object can either be passed in to the function as a `parameter`/`argument` or by the use of the keyword `global`.

```
function exist_user($username, $conn){
  $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :$username');       
  $sth->bindParam(':email', $username);
  $sth->execute();
  return ($sth->rowCount() == 0) ?  true :  false;
}
```

Or:

```
function exist_user($username){
  global $conn;
  $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :$username');       
  $sth->bindParam(':email', $username);
  $sth->execute();
  return ($sth->rowCount() == 0) ?  true :  false;
}
```

I would recommend going with option 1, its easier to read and the `global` keyword is an abomination (personal opinion).

Comment: `:$username` is not valid parameter there. Look closely.

Comment: That is true, but that's another error, this question was about why the `$conn` object is `null` ;)

Comment: It will crash, as not all required parameters are supplied, no?

Comment: It will give an error telling the user that the parameters are incorrect or similar. It will not cause the `$conn` variable to be null.

Comment: @BlitZ Solved the conn problem by adding "require 'database.php' "inside the function.

Comment: @Mi7ai be sure to close the connection after if you are just going to use it in a local scope so that it wont leak or maintain a connection to the db (not sure how php handles the cleanup of local variables, so I might be wrong here).
Personally I'd prefer to reuse the `$conn` variable in other places too, but the way you did it *will* work too :)